# How to fit a gaussian mixture model in R with fixed parameters

Tags: r, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am using R to analyse experimental, two dimensional data via gaussian mixture modeling with the `mclust` package in order to find the mean of each component. I already know something about my data (the number of components and their proportions are defined by the experimental setup) and thought, that the modeling accuracy might increase if I could fix this parameters when fitting the model.

Is this possible? Or is there another package/software to accomplish this?

Example with simulated data:

```
library(mclust)
library(mixtools)

set.seed(3)

n <- c(500,400,400)
mean <- list(c(0.5, 0.6),
             c(0.5, 0.5),
             c(0.7, 0.5))
sigma <- list(matrix(c(0.3, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03),2),
              matrix(c(.02, 0.002, 0.002, .004),2),
              matrix(c(.02, 0.002, 0.002, .004),2))

sim <- rbind(
  data.frame(as.data.frame(rmvnorm(n = n[1], mu = mean[[1]], sigma = sigma[[1]])), dist = as.factor(1)),
  data.frame(as.data.frame(rmvnorm(n = n[2], mu = mean[[2]], sigma = sigma[[2]])), dist = as.factor(2)),
  data.frame(as.data.frame(rmvnorm(n = n[3], mu = mean[[3]], sigma = sigma[[3]])), dist = as.factor(3))
)

SimClust <- Mclust(data = cbind(sim$V1, sim$V2), G=3, modelNames = c("VVV"))
plot(SimClust)
2
0
```

In this example the algorithm fails to find the "real" means. I thought this might work better if one could set the true proportions for the fit.